# Validation of ip-address using tcl

Tags: tcl

Hello frnds m facing problem in this program..cn any tell me where m i making mistake??
m nt able to validate for 255.255.255.255 ip address

```
puts "Enter a valid ip address:"
set string [gets stdin]
if {[regexp {^([1-9]|[1]\d{2}|[2][0-4]\d|25[0-5])((\.\d{0,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3})$} $string match]} {
    puts $string
} else {
    puts "INVALID-ADDRESS"
}
```

Comment: Using a regular expression to validate an IP address is not very nice. Indeed, it will fail on many of the more obscure forms of address as well. I strongly recommend the approaches that Brian's answer describes…

Answer (score 5):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There are dozens of working examples of how to validate IP addresses. See here for some http://wiki.tcl.tk/989

Also if you have TCLlib you can use the **::ip::version** command e.g

```
% package require ip
1.2
% ::ip::version 192.168.0.1
4
% ::ip::version www.google.com
-1
% ::ip::version 192.168.0.333
-1
```

Comment: @Pratibha, does this answer your question? If so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
set ip "1.2.3.4"
if { [ catch[regexp {(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)} $ip man]] } {
    set flag 0
}
set cut [split $ip "."]
set flag "" 
if {[llength $cut] == 4} {
    set flag 1
} else {
    set flag 0 
}
if {[lindex $cut 0] == 0} { 
    set flag  0 
}
foreach nut $cut {
    if {[string length $nut] > 3} {
        set flag 0
    }
    if {$nut > 255} {
        set flag 0 
    }
    set a [split $nut ""]
    if { [lindex $a 0] == 0 } {
        set flag 0
    }
    #set int [lappend mat $nut]
}
if {$flag == 0} { 
    puts "Not a valid IP"
} else {
    puts "IP IS VALID:$man"
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
proc validateIP {IP} {
    if {[regexp {^(?:(\d{1,2})|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))(?:\.((\d{1,2})|(1\d{2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))){3}$} $IP]} {
        puts "$IP is a valid IP"
    } else {
        puts "INVALID-ADDRESS"
    }
}
```

There were some several errors with your regex, specially the placing of the dot was grouped with the first possibility only

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving the easiest pattern for beginners understanding.

```
pattern: /^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
% set ip "192.168.123.23"
192.168.123.23
% regexp {([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+)} $ip match a b c d
1
% if {$a <= 255 & $b <= 255 & $c <= 255 & $d <= 255} {
  puts "this is a valid ip address"
  } else {
  puts "this not a valid ip address"
 }
```

this is a valid ip address

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "enter your ip address"
set ip [gets stdin]
regexp {([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)} "$ip" match 1st 2nd 3rd 4rth

if {$1st < 256 & $2nd < 256 & $3rd <256 & $4rth<256} { // numbers in range?
  puts "valid IP address"
} else { 
  puts "not valid IP address"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set ip 100.12.230.250

set mat [regexp -nocase {(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$} $ip match]


if {$mat == 1} {
    puts "Valid Ip"
} else {
   puts "Invalid Ip"
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.