# Data Capture Issue using expect in tcl

Tags: expect

I have one doubt in expect. I want to store the result of command in a string variable. Can anyone tell me what is the mistake in my code? It is not working. I have used `expect_out(buffer)` but its not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
package require Expect
set Argu1 [lindex $argv 0]
set Argu2 [lindex $argv 1]

if {$argc == 2} {

    if {[regexp {^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|[2][5][0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[
        0-4]\d|[2][5][0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|[2][5][0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]
        \d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|[2][5][0-5])$} $Argu1 match ]} {
        puts "VALID IP-ADDRESS"
        set timeout $Argu2-1
        spawn ping $Argu1
        expect "Expect"
        set string $expect_out(buffer)
        puts $string
        puts "SUCCESS"
        exit 
    } else { 
        puts "INVALID IP-ADDRESS"
    } 
} else { 
    puts "YOU HAVE TO GIVE TWO ARGUMENTS\n FIRST ARGUMENT SHOULD BE 
    IP-ADDRESS \n SECOND ARGUMENT SHOULD BE THE NUMBER OF PACKETS
    YOU WANT TO SEND"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reluctant to answer your question, as you haven't responded to my answer on another question. However, seeing as nobody else has responded, I'll try to help you out.

I don't think you need to use **$expect_out(buffer)** here. Assuming that a ping returning "0% loss" or "0% packet loss" means the ping was successful, you could try the following (untested). Obviously, you can change the "0%" to whatever you want to signify success.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
package require Expect
set Argu1 [lindex $argv 0]
set Argu2 [lindex $argv 1]

if {$argc == 2} {

    if {[regexp {^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|[2][5][0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[
        0-4]\d|[2][5][0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|[2][5][0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]
        \d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|[2][5][0-5])$} $Argu1 match ]} {
        puts "VALID IP-ADDRESS"
        set timeout $Argu2-1
        spawn ping $Argu1
        expect {
          "0%" {puts "The IP address was successfully pinged"}
          "default" {puts "Could not ping this IP address"}
        }
        exit 
    } else { 
        puts "INVALID IP-ADDRESS"
    } 
} else { 
    puts "YOU HAVE TO GIVE TWO ARGUMENTS\n FIRST ARGUMENT SHOULD BE 
    IP-ADDRESS \n SECOND ARGUMENT SHOULD BE THE NUMBER OF PACKETS
    YOU WANT TO SEND"
}
```

The reason I suggest "0%" is as follows. If you do a successful ping from a Windows machine you will see something like this (note the "0% loss"):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian>ping 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
```

From a Unix machine, it might look like this (note the "0% packet loss") :

```
[brian@rex 4]$ ping -c 1 192.168.1.87
PING 192.168.1.87 (192.168.1.87) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.87: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=42.1 ms

--- 192.168.1.87 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 42.153/42.153/42.153/0.000 ms, pipe 2
```

You could pick many indicators of a successful ping, I chose the fact that there was a 0% loss of packets (a clear indicator of success). The `expect` command searches the result of the ping and if it finds "0%", it outputs "The IP address was successfully pinged".

Comment: Thanks Brian for helping me...but still i have one doubt..actually i didn't understand the concept of 0%... and one more thing.. i didn't understand what you mentioned above..which question are talked about?

Comment: Hi @PratibhaTomar, I will edit the question to explain the concept of 0% - it's just one way to determine a succesful ping. The question I was refering to is this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633281/validation-of-ip-address-using-tcl

Comment: I've added more info to the answer now - does that explain it better?